# Create shortcut with arguments

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments, cmder

I would like to create desktop shortcut to cmder with argument, for example SSH connect. I was trying:

```
"C:\Program Files\cmder\Cmder.exe" ssh root@localhost
```

But unfortunately I getting that response:

[image]

Comment: Use a cmder startup script. See [Using SSH agent on Windows with Cmder and without eval](https://andrewbridge.wordpress.com/2015/04/28/using-ssh-agent-on-windows-with-cmder-and-without-eval/)

Comment: I adjusted my answer for your needs. Let me know if it works out.

Comment: `"'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."` Otherwise I preffer run app with binded command.

Answer (score 3):

*Cmder is not a ConEmu. `cmder.exe` is just a "loader" for `ConEmu.exe`. And `cmder.exe` has its own set of parameters which have nothing in common with `ConEmu.exe`.*

The error message unambiguously tells you to use `/START` switch. And if you run `ConEmu.exe` you have to use `-run` switch.

Comment: http://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html

there is no -run. I tried `"C:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu64.exe" cmd ssh`

but:
`'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: It's user responsibility to have `ssh.exe` available in `%PATH%` if they do not specify full path top executable. ConEmu can't magically run "something"!

Comment: Of course, my bad...

Comment: So setting the path environment variable to the bin where ssh.exe is located, I got that. What is the explicit line of command for a batch file say, then? I tried several but the window disappears, so I'm pretty sure I have the syntax screwy. And I just started using this tool for about 15 minutes tops now. But familiar with cmd and batch in general, but not ConEmu(64).exe

Comment: @ejbytes So, you want to learn how to use `cmd.exe`? Than run `cmd /?` and read its output. Also, some info is here: http://conemu.github.io/en/CmdPrompt.html

Comment: The part of your answer I don't understand: "The error message unambiguously tells you to use /START switch. And if you run ConEmu.exe you have to use -run switch."   How would you use the "run" switch for ConEmu.exe? What is the actual full line if input?

Comment: Docs (http://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html) shows examples. Simplest usage: `ConEmu.exe -run cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution might be to create a task with CMDER. I will put a screenshot. To SSH easily, I understand the chore it is to do the same thing over and over again. Making a task: http://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html

1. Add a task with pulldown arrow
2. Choose, Setup Tasks
3. On the GUI, click '+', so add new task
4. a) Lets name the task b)let's give it a hot key sequence shortcut c)command to execute
5. Save the task, "Save Settings"

Lastly, run the ask with the shortcut sequence.

[image]

Another possible solution worth investigating:
I use a nifty program AHK, AutoHotKey to input many of data arguments automatically during a day. AHK is really slick and I use it almost daily.
https://autohotkey.com/ Once installed, a hotkey could send a string of text to any input console.

Comment: I did that. When I open file.bat I see fast cmd.exe blink and nothing else.

Comment: I just realized that you are using a program. My apologies. It's a spicy version that uses DOS and Linux I just read. I see. So you want to ssh into an I.P. address, but then have your windows open, which is "Cmdr". It looks like what I use, Gitbash software for Linux utilities while using my Windows machine. I see. I'll take a closer look.